# window.onload function not running on refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an window.onload function that does not run when a user manually refreshes the page. I have noticed that on the page refresh, the URL is appended with a # at the end, but I don't know if that has anything to do with the error. The function correctly executes when first loaded, but not after a refresh.

```
window.onload = function() {

            alert("HERE");
            var a = document.getElementById("link1");
            a.onclick = function() {
                var current = window.location.href;
                alert(current);

                if (current.indexOf("&page=") != -1) {
                    current = current.substring(0,current.indexOf("&page="));
                }
                var nextPage = current + "&page=link1"
                window.location.replace(nextPage);
                return false;
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: It seems as though it is working in Chrome, but not Safari.

Also, additional information, my a tag looks like this:

```
<a id='link1' href='#'>Link 1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using :

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
     });
```

instead.
check if it helps..

Comment: This caused the link to not work even on the initial page load in both Chrome and Safari. When clicking the link, it now simply appends a # to the end of the URL.